# How to set pip config for virtual environments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to use `pip config set global.extra-index-url www.example.com` but just for my virtual environment rather than the system-wide pip.

When I run the aforementioned command, it edits system-wide `pip.conf` file. So every time I run `pip install <package>` after that, even outside of a virtual environment, it checks [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) for packages.

Ideally, I want it to only check that extra index URL when I install packages in a given virtual environment and nowhere else.

I know that I am able to manually place a `pip.conf` file in the virtual environment directory to do it. But I want to know if there's a command I can run via `pip` to configure the `pip.conf` file without manually editing and placing it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add in the `--site` flag:

```
pip config set --site global.extra-index-url ...
```

Comment: Ah! I kept using `site.extra-index-url` thinking I was meant to replace `global` with `site` rather than adding it as an option.

Comment: Yeah, it's a really confusing CLI - the section of the key actually refers to the pip subcommand (install, download, freeze etc) and not the site.  So `global.extra-index-url` means using that config on all subcommands.